# Multiple .get(...) with same route

Tags: reactjs, express, bookshelf.js

I am trying add router.get('/:name', ...) that will return a point from the database based on the ':name' parameter.

routes/points.js

```
import express from 'express'
import Points from '/path/models/points'

let router = express.Router()

router.get('/:session', (req, res) => {
    Points.query({...}).fetchAll().then(point => {
        //returns points based on sessionId
    })
})

export default router
```

When I try to add another '.get', all that is returned when I use a different parameter from 'session' is undefined, because the original router.get is used and is looking for 'session'.

Is there a way to add another 'get' that takes different parameters?

Comment: It's a bad idea to put parameters at the root level of your routing precisely because of this, as pretty much *anything* will match to that parameter. Consider redefining that route to something like `/sessions/:session` throughout your project and your problem will go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on my comment:

```
import express from 'express';
import Points from '/path/models/points';

let router = express.Router();

router.get('/sessions/:session', (req, res) => {
  Points.query({...}).fetchAll().then(point => {
    //returns points based on sessionId
  });
});

router.get('/names/:name', (req, res) => {
  .. actual code here ..
});

export default router;
```

Now if you *really* insist on having a single agnostic entry point for your query, you could use a single route, and use the actual DB query to search both the `session_id` and `name` fields in your DB for a match to your agnostic parameter. Something like:

```
import express from 'express';
import Points from '/path/models/points';

let router = express.Router();

router.get('/:points', (req, res) => {
  Points.query({...}).fetchAll().then(point => {
    //returns points based on sessionId OR name
  });
});

export default router;
```

However I still believe it's a terrible idea to have parameter matching at the root level.

As for having two routes concurrently matching parameters at the root level, that's just impossible as the first route defined will receive all incoming requests, while the second will receive none, simply because there is no way to tell a `:session` parameter from a `:name` parameter. To node/express, they're both the same, i.e. they both match *anything* that follows the root forward slash.

Comment: @Wilson Just added an alternative way of doing it, although I still believe my original solution is the way to go. And you're welcome ;)